# How to show li content on top of absolutely positioned element?

Tags: css, border, gradient

I need to style `li` element with `border-radius` and gradient border, so that it will look like this:
[image]

**Html:**

```
<li class="myTab">
Hello World!
</li>
```

Problem is that text inside of `li` is not wrapped in anything and I can't change it. I'm using `LESS`, tried doing:

```
.TAB() {
        #gradient > .linear(top; #655724 0%, #d0704c 50%, #b24e31 100%);
        border-radius: 15px;
        position: relative;

        &::before{
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            width: ~'calc(100% - 4px)';
            height: ~'calc(100% - 4px)';
            #gradient > .radialEllipse(center; closest-corner; #b4812a 0%, #374e0a 100%);
            border-radius: 14px;
        }
    }
```

Looks good except for the text being covered by pseudo element. Is there any way to bring text in the front without html changes?

*P.S. I'm also not allowed to use z-index T^T*

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/6gfvmt40/)

Answer (score -1):

When you work with absolutely positioned elements be sure place then in the right order along Z-axis by z-index property.

And when you work with absolutely positioned elements be sure to place all content(i.e. text etc) inside appropriate tagElement in your case place all labels inside P tag.

Here is code:

```css
body{
  background: #6b7023;
}
ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.myTab{
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #655724 0%, #d0704c 50%, #b24e31 100%);
 border-radius: 15px;
 position: relative;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.myTab::before{
  content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: calc(100% - 4px);
 height: calc(100% - 4px);
 background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse closest-corner at center, #b4812a 0%, #374e0a 100%);
 border-radius: 14px;
  z-index:9;
}
.myTab p {
  z-index:10;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="myTab"><p>1st tab</p></li>
<li class="myTab"><p>2nd tab</p></li>
<li class="myTab"><p>3rd tab</p></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The OP cannot change the HTML or use `z-index`. Your answer does **both**.

Comment: sorry for that. Try this .myTab::after{
  content: '1st tab';
 position: absolute;
} and place it after the code ..myTab::before{...}

Comment: That won't work either, since list is being populated by javascript and it also can't be changed.